# Trouble using stackPush() in LWJGL 3.1.4 - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gradle, stack, lwjgl

I've been working on a project in which we use LWJGL. We have no problems running this line in version 3.1.3

```
val stack: MemoryStack = stackPush
```

However, this line trips up when create a Gradle project using 3.1.4, in which the native libraries are pulled in by Gradle, using this build.gradle:

```
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'scala'

switch ( OperatingSystem.current() ) {
    case OperatingSystem.WINDOWS:
        project.ext.lwjglNatives = "natives-windows"
        break
    case OperatingSystem.LINUX:
        project.ext.lwjglNatives = "natives-linux"
        break
    case OperatingSystem.MAC_OS:
        project.ext.lwjglNatives = "natives-macos"
        break
}

project.ext.lwjglVersion = "3.1.4"  //if this is 3.1.3 it works

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl:$lwjglVersion"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-opencl:$lwjglVersion"
    runtime "org.lwjgl:lwjgl:$lwjglVersion:$lwjglNatives"
}
```

and I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.limit(I)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryAccess$MemoryAccessorUnsafe.getCapacityOffset(MemoryAccess.java:159)
at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryAccess$MemoryAccessorUnsafe.<clinit>(MemoryAccess.java:132)
at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryAccess.getInstance(MemoryAccess.java:31)
at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.<clinit>(MemoryUtil.java:62)
at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.<init>(MemoryStack.java:60)
at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.create(MemoryStack.java:81)
at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.create(MemoryStack.java:70)
at java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:284)
at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.stackGet(MemoryStack.java:603)
at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.stackPush(MemoryStack.java:612)
at JavaFXCanvas.main(JavaFXCanvas.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
[LWJGL] [MemoryAccessor] Unsupported JVM detected, this will likely result in low performance. Please inform LWJGL developers.
```

My suspicion is that somewhere a misplaced dll is causing issues, but haven't had luck tracking that down. Has anyone else encountered similar issues with 3.1.4 of LWJGL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error and from Slack Spasi commented:

> the problem is https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4774077, workaround: either use Java 9 or the `3.1.4 snapshot 8` (it's identical to `3.1.4` except compiled with Java 8)